# Calling service from one docker container to other container is causing net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED

Tags: node.js, docker, express, docker-compose

i am running application with multi containers as below..

**feeder** - is a simple nodejs container from image node:alpine

**api** - is nodejs container with expressjs from image node:alpine

**ui-app** - is react app container from image node:alpine

i am trying to call the api service in ui-app i am getting error as below

[image to Console Log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XZdsz.png)

[image to Console Log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dtSq3.png)

not sure what is causing the problem

if i access the services as http://192.168.99.100/ping it works (that is my docker machine default ip)...
but if i use container name like http://api:3200/ping it is not working...? please help..

the below is my docker-compose.

```
version: '3'

services:
  feeder:
    build: ./feeder
    container_name: feeder
    tty: true
    depends_on:
      - redis
    links:
      - redis
    environment:
      - IS_FROM_DOCKER=true
    ports:
      - "3100:3100"
    networks:
      - hmdanet        
  api:
    build: ./api
    container_name: api
    tty: true
    depends_on:
      - feeder
    links:
      - redis
    environment:
      - IS_FROM_DOCKER=true
    ports:
      - "3200:3200"
    networks:
      hmdanet:
        aliases:
          - "hmda-api"
  ui-app:
    build: ./ui-app
    container_name: ui-app
    tty: true
    depends_on:
      - api
    links:
      - api
    environment:
      - IS_FROM_DOCKER=true
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    networks:
      - hmdanet          
  redis:
    image: redis:latest    
    ports:
      - '6379:6379'
    networks:
      - hmdanet          
networks:
  hmdanet:
    driver: bridge
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only use service name as a domain name when you are inside a container. In you case it's your browser making the call, it does not know what `api` is. In you web app, you should have an env like base url set to the ip of your docker machine or localhost.